# programmatically adding button to UIToolbar

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am programmatically creating a UIToolbar with this code:

```
pickerTB = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:pickerTB];
```

How do i add one single button to it? It needs to say "Done" and the button must be able to call a method later on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this, If you want to add DONE button on right side of uitoolbar then add flexible button before  done button

```
 UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
 UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButton)];

 NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton, doneButton, nil];


 [toolbar setItems:itemsArray];

-(void)doneButton
{
}
```

// change toolbar style

```
 [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

//change bar button color

```
[doneButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: how to do the translucent black color?

Comment: the button remains blue :/

Comment: it is the one you provided

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
pickerTB.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done:)],nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will really helpful to add button to the UIToolbar present in keyboard or pickerview.

For example:
If you want "Done" button to be inserted in the toolbar of the pickerview. you just have to follow simple steps as follows.

Step 1:
Have to include this code inside "viewDidLoad" to create "Done" button in UIToolbar. "textBoxText" is the name of the Text field.

```
    // create done button in toolbar.
    doneToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    doneToolbar.items =   [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.PickerDoneButtonTapped))]
    doneToolbar.sizeToFit()
    textBoxText.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
```

Step 2:
Code the function of "Done" button that has included in the UIToolbar. I have given that if  "Done" button is tapped the PickerView have to disable.

```
func PickerDoneButtonTapped()
{
    textBoxText.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Step 3:
Have to call the function in "viewDidload"

```
self.PickerDoneButtonTapped()
```

Output:

[image]